# Compensation of reactive energy

Tags: ac

I need to measure electric consumption cost of a machine.
My point of measurement is at machine but up the line inside company transformer we have compensation of energy power.

Correct me if my understanding of reactive power and compensation is wrong:

So you have capacitive reactive component and inductive reactive power and both of them are opposite so if they are equal they cancel out and you have 0 reactive power.

Compensation works in a similar way that based on cos fi measurement it generates opposite reactive power to cancel current reactive power in order to achive cos fi of 1.0, meaning only active power.
In case of compensation we are left with only active power which is getting charged by electric company(considering compensation would be perfect). The effect of compensation on active power is neglible.

So since we have compensation of reactive power later up the line i am guessing i can forget reactive energy.

I can ignore apparent power as that is more or less for calculations, theory, etc?

How wrong is my thinking ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparent power is what is heating your lines and blowing your fuses.

Answer (score 0):

You are right when you compare inductive and capacitive loads. The reactive power taken by inductors or effectively inductive loads like motors can be compensated by inserting capacitance in parallel with the load. Indutive load respectively can compensate the reactive power caused by capacitors. Specially controlled synchronous motors can be used as automatic compensators  because they can behave as well capacitively and inductively depending on their magnetization current.

If you add to your plant a new machine  you must calculate its current consumption (for cables, their joints, fuses, breakers) from its apparent power. Taking into the account only the real power gives too low estimate. The compensator at the mains AC feed point of your plant may be able to remove the extra current caused by the reactive power from the net current your plant takes, but that doesn't happen in the wires and fuses between the machine and the compensator in the mains AC input of your plant. Your maybe heavily inductive machine and the capacitance in the compensator are together a big resonant circuit where the current can be substantially higher than what's taken from the mains AC feed of your plant.

Not asked: The power factor -concept has gradually got a new dimension which was not remarkable 100 years ago. Compensating inductive and capacitive reactive power was 100 years ago already as important as today to reduce the total current, but today electronic devices are a substantial part of the total electricity consumption. They tend to be non-linear loads i.e. the current occurs as non-sinusoidal pulses. We say that the current contains harmonic components. They increase the total current, too. Inductors nor capacitors do not compensate it, an electronic compensator (=electronic power factor corrector) is needed.

In many countries computers and other high consumption electronic devices must have that type of compensator inbuilt to the power supply. It's quite effective, because one must  add only few parts to the existing power supply to keep its input current approximately sinusoidal. A whole plant wide electronic power factor corrector would be a big and complex device and a new point where a fault would generate a total blackout.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say whether you are a domestic or industrial consumer. It doesn't alter the physics, but it does alter the scale of the problem, to the point that typically, electricity companies only charge domestic consumers for real power, but charge industrial consumers some sort of surcharge for reactive power as well. This is why industrial users will usually have some sort of site-wide compensation, to reduce what they are charged for their electricity supply.

A reactive load draws a current, and that current has to be paid for somehow, in heating of the cables, and provisioning larger cross section for the cables. Industrial users, who may run a factory full of motors with a poor power factor for instance, will be encouraged (by their electricity bills) to supply their reactive power locally from a compensator, rather than handle it remotely along with the real power from a distant generator via expensive infrastructure like transformers and transmission lines.

I'm not sure why domestic customers are only charged for real power, perhaps it's a 'fairness' thing. However, regulations requiring internal power factor correction for appliances above a certain power rating, and very poor power factor things like flourescent tubes, mean that domestic users generally have quite a good power factor anyway.